# Unity UI text not displayed?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Why is the text displayed on the stage but not in the game?

[image]

Comment: First thing I'd check is if you're trying to display text that is bigger than the text box - make the box larger or the text smaller to check this. Then check if the scales of the text/box/canvas (if applicable) are as expected.

Comment: Check if you have multiple Canvases in your scene :D And check if the camera sees that layer that the text/canvas is on

Answer (score 5):

To me this looks like a Canvas issue:

1. Make sure the canvas scale dynamically, "Scale with Screen Size"
2. Check Reference Resolution
3. Make sure the Text Anchor Preset's is correct
4. You should probably using "Best Fit" in the UI Text Components to make sure the text is dynamically aligned

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if i'm allowed to answer on a 3 year old question but maybe this is going to help someone.
I had the same problem with the text showing in sceneview but not in gameview and in my case I was instantiating a 2D object with a TextMeshPro component.

After an hour I found out that I was setting the z component of the objects scale to 0 which leads to the mentioned problem.
If your text is a component or child of any object, that object or its parent is not allowed to have a z-scale of 0.

[my example: if anvilBackround z-scale is 0, the quitText object does not show the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieWl7.png)

Answer (score 0):

So the issue for me, was that my text was a component of canvas.
When I put it as an object in the scene, it rendered.

Answer (score -1):

5 - Check that your color isn't transparent.
I had the same problem seconds ago.